# Docker container as Windows service start before login

Tags: windows, docker, scheduled-tasks, daemon, docker-daemon

I have created a container via Docker Desktop on a Windows PC and would now like to start this container like a service or daemon during system startup. If successful, the container would be accessible from its own network via 192.168.178.35:80 without a user having to log in and start Docker.

This is really not my favorite topic but I tried to learn about Windows task scheduling.

As you can see here I wrote a short powershell script that starts Docker Desktop.exe and then the container.

```
start "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe"
sleep 10
docker start 9df2014cdb06
exit
```

I assigned the script to the SYSTEM user in the task scheduler. (see screenshot 1)[image]

Unfortunately, 192.168.178.35:80 cannot be reached when the system is booted. When I log in, I see that various Docker background processes in Task manager. (See screenshot 2).[image]

However, Docker is no longer accessible in Powershell. (See error message)

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker ps  
error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be 
run with elevated privileges to connect.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json": 
open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

And starting it from the desktop icon does not succeed either. Instead, the message appears that Docker is already running.
[image]

But my container is not running.

How do I get my container running and accessible on Windows after system startup and before user login?